# How to get JSON Object using given path in string variable c#

Tags: c#, json, object, dynamic

```
var string = "test.data"

var json = "{'test':{'data':[{'details':{'id':'1','name':'user1'}},{'details':{'id':'2','name':'user2'}}]}}"
```

var output = **json.string**

Comment: Hi, Welcome to stackoverflow. Could you please update your question with what output you are expecting and what you tried so far?

Comment: JSON.Parse(json)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [JsonPath](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonSelectTokenJsonPath.htm) for getting value based on path,

```
var json = JObject.Parse(@"{
       'test':{
         'data':[
              {
               'details':
                   {
                     'id':'1',
                     'name':'user1'
                   }
               },
              {
                'details':
                    {
                       'id':'2',
                       'name':'user2'
                    }
               }
           ]
         }
     }");


JToken data = json.SelectToken("$.test.data");
Console.WriteLine(data);
```

[.Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1elVqv)

Comment: Based on your example if I want to get all 'id' from details. How can we get ??. Can you please add solution for that

Comment: You can play with json path check fiddle: http://jsonpath.com/ Check for path `$.phoneNumbers[:].type` for sample json. It would be great if spend some time, try out different ways to get different properties. if still it did not help you let me know I will update my answer

Comment: Thanks. Your answer is helpful for me

Comment: You can use emoji now to say thanks _/\\_

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are asking for, newtonsoft json library has been used in my example.

```
   var json = "{'test':{'data':[{'details':{'id':'1','name':'user1'}},{'details':{'id':'2','name':'user2'}}]}}";

        var jObj = JObject.Parse(json);

        var result = jObj.SelectToken("test.data")?.ToString();

        // result

        // [
        // {
        //     "details": {
        //         "id": "1",
        //         "name": "user1"
        //     }
        // },
        // {
        //     "details": {
        //         "id": "2",
        //         "name": "user2"
        //     }
        // }
        // ]
```

Comment: And also I would  recommend  checking newtonsoft documentation for examples, etc.

And as one of the comments asking you for is always try add expected output to you question as  I am purely "going blind" here

Answer (score 0):

To read the JSON file using its path. You can create a common method that accepts the path and you can read it.

```
using System;
using System.IO;

public static string ReadAllTextFromPath(string path)
        {
            var filePath= AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + path;
            var fileData = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
            return fileData ;
        }
```

If you want to convert the JSON string into an object then use the below.

```
var jsonString = ReadAllTextFromPath(filepath);//your JSON string
var jObject = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(jsonString);
```

if you want to select a particular value from a JSON data, use the selecttoken

```
var object = (string)jObject.SelectToken("test.data");
//If you know "test.data" data having a structure of Model class, you can cast that class.
```